# Firebase: Send Messages to a JavaScript Client (react-native) via device id

Tags: javascript, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native

Via: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive is it possible to send notifications to device tokens such that you might get via react-native app (it's still just js)..?  ...So sending to Android app (react-native) vs a web app in the browser.

I currently have push notifications setup in the java layer but if it can all be done via js, albeit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Cloud Messaging for the Web (FCM.js for short) depends on the browser's implementation of Web Push for the transport of messages.

A React Native app is very much not a browser-based app. So you cannot use FCM.js to receive message in your React Native app (unless somebody went out of their way to embed a compatible browser in the app).

Comment: Super bummer!  Not firebase's fault but a mobile application platform like react-native should have a push notification solution that doesn't require the dev to write a custom module, but nevertheless thanks for confirming my suspicions...

Comment: There is a third-party library in development binding many of the Firebase features from the native (iOS and Android) SDKs. See https://github.com/fullstackreact/react-native-firestack

Comment: Hmmm... This might be something that will be worth contributing to: https://github.com/fullstackreact/react-native-firestack/blob/master/README.md#cloud-messaging. Thanks for the link!

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen there's a lot broken in firestack and the fcm implementation included in this - at least on ios, I was the author of the formerly upcoming v3 branch of firestack that aimed to standardise everything, but I eventually ended up creating https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase - it's well tested, updated frequently and any issues do get picked up quickly. There is a full FCM solution built in for android and ios with custom notification support.

Comment: "A React Native app is very much not a browser-based app. So you cannot use FCM.js to receive message in your React Native app (unless somebody went out of their way to embed a compatible browser in the app)." -> does this still apply?